# What is the best way to call Servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

Currently working on Java Web Application.

Requirement is to keep Web application as simple as possible.

There are multiple opinion across team members about calling Servlet.

So question is what is best way to call servlet in terms of ease, technical feasibility, Scalability, and Testing.

1. Calling Servlet from jsp --> Its standard practice but people want to try other options.
2. Calling Servlet from html page.
3. Calling Servlet from javascript.

Note:

1. We are aware about how jsp/servlet works
2. We know how to call servlet from html page and javascript but since its initial phase, so want to confirm before we implement.

Comment: There's only one way to call a servlet: make an HTTP request from a client.  That can be a JSP or an HTML page or an AJAX call.  The simplicity of the app isn't determined by which one you choose for a given context.

Comment: Hello @duffymo by simplicity I mean implementation part. as I mentioned we are aware about how to call servlet but just wanted to confirm about html and javascript part as it is new to us.

Comment: I mean implementation part, too.  I would say JSPs are an old style; early 2000s vintage.  Single page web apps would be the current thinking.

Comment: @duffymo Can you explain more about "Single page web apps". Thanks for your support.

Comment: could you please learn how to use Google and type "single page web apps" into a search box?